# Expanded Widget occupies the whole screen

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-listview

When I use the Expanded widget with my ListView in a Column or a Row, it occupies the entire screen and doesn't fit to the size of the list. Is there any way to fit my Column or Row to the exact size of my list returned with the ListView? I don't want it to occupy the entire screen as I have two buttons which get pushed to the end of the screen because of the unnecessary space the Expanded widget takes. And the Listview doesn't seem to work without Expanded widget.

Comment: the following widget tree `Column[Expanded>ListView, Row[Button, Button]]` should work: you will see a list view and 2 buttons on the bottom

Comment: Still getting overflow at the bottom. `Column[Row[Flexible(flex:2), Flexible(flex:3, child: Container>Column[Text,Listview])], Row[Button, Button]]` this is the widget tree I'm using.

Comment: List view has to be a child of expanded

Comment: I tried it, but getting failed assertion hasSize for Container

Answer (score 2):

You have 3 options to solve this issue:

**First way:** remove `Expanded` and use the property `shrinkWrap` in the `ListView` and set it to `true`, this is the easiest way but this has some drawbacks, please check out [Flutter official docs for more details.](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/widgets/ListView-class.html)

**Second way**: remove `Expanded` and replace it with `SizedBox` or `Container` and set an explicit `height` like 300.

**Third way**: use `CustomScrollView` as your body and use `SliverListView` instead of `ListView` and use `SliverToBoxAdapter` with `Row` as a child, please read the [Flutter official docs for more detail](https://flutter.dev/docs/development/ui/advanced/slivers) about using Slivers

Comment: do you have any resource, from where I can follow sliverlist? Also, do you think sliverlist will solve this problem? [https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65048354/any-alternative-to-expanded-widgets-using-with-listview-builder?noredirect=1#comment114999644_65048354]

Comment: can you share the widget tree for the third way you mentioned?